# printing the content of a file, but getting an int as an output (number of characters in the file) in Python

Tags: python, text-files

I wrote a function that copies the content of one file to a new file.
the function gets 2 parameters:

1. the directory of the copied file
2. the directory of the new file.

When I try to print the content of the copied file, I get the **content** of the file (which is what I want), But when I try to do the same thing with the new file, I get the **number of characters** inside the file (14 in this case).

I don't understand why do I get 2 different outputs with the same (at list as per my understanding) lines of code.

Would be happy to get some help, thank you!

Here's my code:

```
# creating the file that's going to be copied:
with open(source_link, 'w') as f:
    f.write('Copy this file')

# the function:
def copy_file_content(source, destination):
    
    # getting the content of the copied file:
    f1 = open(source, 'r')
    copied_file = f1.read()
    f1.close()
    
    # putting the content of the copied file in the new file:
    f2 = open(destination, 'w')
    new_file = f2.write(copied_file)
    f2.close

    # print old file:
    print(copied_file)
    
    print('***')
    # print new file:
    print(new_file)
    
copy_file_content(source = source_link, destination = dest_link)
```

Output:

```
Copy this file
***
14
```

Comment: When you do: `new_file = f2.write(...)` you get the number of characters written. If you have created a new file from `copied_file` then it stands to reason that the new file will also contain `copied_file`.

Comment: Your `print` statement does not print the content of the new file - you close it with `f2.close` and never read it back. As @quamrana explained, the varible `new_file` will contain the number of copied bytes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.read()` returns the file contents, which is why when `copied_file` is set to `f1.read()`, you can print the contents out. However, `.write()` performs the write operation on the file and then returns the number of characters written.

Therefore `new_file` contains the number of characters written. Rather than setting the value of `new_file` to `f2.write()`, you must open the new file again in read mode, and then perform `file.read()`

```py
def copy_file_content(source, destination):

    # getting the content of the copied file:
    with open(source, 'r') as f1:
        copied_file = f1.read()
    
    # putting the content of the copied file in the new file:
    with open(destination, 'w') as f2:
         f2.write(copied_file)

    with open(destination, "r") as f2_read:
         new_file = f2_read.read()

    # print old file:
    print(copied_file)
    
    print('***')
    # print new file:
    print(new_file)
    
copy_file_content(source = source_link, destination = dest_link)
```

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects:%7E:text=f.write(string)%20writes%20the%20contents%20of%20string%20to%20the%20file%2C%20returning%20the%20number%20of%20characters%20written.):

> f.write(string) writes the contents of string to the file, returning the number of characters written.

Opposed to `f.read()`, which returns file contents.

If you want to read contents of `copied_file`, you will need to open it again in read mode:

```py
with open(destination, 'r') as f:
    new_file = f.read(copied_file)
```